# Set a shrunken camera preview to have the correct image aspect ration with respect to width

Tags: java, android, image-processing, android-camera

So in my app I am displaying a camera preview that does not take up the entire screen. I am manually setting the display but I am getting an incorrect image aspect ratio. I am setting the width of display to be half of the current screen size. I then want to set the height in relation to the width and keep the correct image aspect ratio. How do I set the camera previews height while still maintaining the correct ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using this

```
 private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height)
{
    Camera.Size result=null;
    Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
    for (Camera.Size size : p.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height) {
            if (result==null) {
                result=size;
            } else {
                int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
                int newArea=size.width*size.height;

                if (newArea>resultArea) {
                    result=size;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

[The AOSP Camera uses a `PreviewFrameLayout`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_camera/blob/master/src/com/android/camera/PreviewFrameLayout.java) as a wrapper around the `SurfaceView` for the preview. They call `setAspectRatio()` on the `PreviewFrameLayout` based on the aspect ratio of the preview size they chose from the `Camera`, and `PreviewFrameLayout` scales the `SurfaceView` accordingly.

Since `PreviewFrameLayout` is open source, there's nothing stopping you from cloning it into your own project, as I did in [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/Preview).

So, in your case, you'd set the `PreviewFrameLayout` to be the desired maximum size ("half of the current screen size", which I'm hoping that you're accomplishing using a `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight`), teach it the aspect ratio, put the `SurfaceView` in the `PreviewFrameLayout`, and you should be good to go.

Note that you should be able to set the `android:layout_gravity` on the `SurfaceView` to center it within the `PreviewFrameLayout`.

Comment: Couldnt I do this a more simple way by setting the `FrameLayout` to 50% of the screens width then setting the `FrameLayout` height and the the camera preview would auto fill it

Comment: @WillJamieson: If you think that's simpler than using code that does all of that for you, you are welcome to do so. Just remember that the aspect ratio is driven by the selected preview frame size -- if your `SurfaceView` is not sized with the same aspect ratio, the imagery will be stretched.

Comment: I checked out your code, and it is exactly what I'm looking for. However, I can't get this to work smoothly in portrait mode. Do you have any idea how I can get that to work?

Comment: @Ole-M: "I can't get this to work smoothly in portrait mode" -- since I do not know what "smoothly" means in this case, let alone what that has to do with portrait mode, I cannot really help you.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Okay, what I was referring to was the aspect ratio. But I fixed it after a while. Just had to switch height and width in setAspectRatio()